# Does every Stack Overflow question really save 90 minutes of developer time?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams, advertising

I recently saw the following Stack Overflow for Teams advertisement while using the site in desktop mode:

[image: screen capture of ad]

Can someone make public the research behind what led to this statistic?  For example, if the Stack Overflow question/answer were not available, what would the main alternative be for solving the problem?

Comment: It's an average. That one git answer that saved over a thousand years of developer time may be skewing the average slightly.

Comment: Good to know; then maybe I should also be asking what the median amount of time saved is.

Comment: Not all developer time is created equal.

Comment: I'm 90% sure that it's from the [2019 survey results](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/04/09/the-2019-stack-overflow-developer-survey-results-are-in/): _We asked respondents to think about the last time they solved coding problems with and without our site. The data indicates that Stack Overflow saves a developer 30 to **90 minutes of time** per week!_ (emphasis mine)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! I am wondering the same as @BhargavRao? But those would then not really be saying the same thing. I'll check next week after the holiday with marketing and see what they were relying on for this ad.

Comment: That ad doesn't say anything about questions. The majority of new questions are garbage.  Answers however are still valuable, which is what the ad says.

Comment: It's also weird that they use a statistic from Public Q&A, and suppose that that somehow vouches for the Private Q&A platform... To me, the ad isn't persuasive at all, it only encourages me to use Stack Overflow as it stands publicly, it doesn't inspire me to want a team at all.

Comment: @JK. Agreed, but in my mind a great answer doesn't exist without a question, and the question in that case would most likely also be considered good.  Yes, most new questions these days don't add much value at all.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen somehow you've made jump from "*answer found* on SO" to "*every question* on SO" - my guess question on average would be time sink, the redeeming quality for SO is most question are never *found* after 15 minutes of fame on first page of "newest questions"...

Comment: Only when you don't spend 90 minutes going through bazillion similar questions and answers trying to find answer for exact problem you are having and none of them helps...

Comment: I'm pretty sure some answers saved me from days of gruelling debugging and divination attempts. But I'd say 95% of the stuff I do, Stack Overflow saves me the time of having to try and piece something together myself from poor documentation. 90 minutes in total per week sounds pretty reasonable as an average, but definitely not per answer.

Comment: @BhargavRao So it's a false/misleading advertisement? Because 30-90mins turned into "90mins average".

Comment: The number given is probably not really covered by the data but up to 90 minutes might work.

Comment: i wish someone captured the original image separately as now that as it was fixed, the image in the question doesn't make sense anymore

Comment: What does saving time on SO have to do with teams? just sounds like piggybacking a paid product off the backs of a decade of hard working devs asking/answering/curating posts.

Comment: ... but then you spend the other 89 minutes browsing Hot Network Questions.

Answer (score 22):

Here is the relevant result from the [SO Developer Survey 2019](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019#community-_-how-much-time-does-stack-overflow-save-developers):

> How Much Time Does Stack Overflow Save Developers?
>
> 0-10 minutes
>   22.7%
>
> 11-30 minutes
>   40.8%
>
> 31-60 minutes
>   19.9%
>
> 60+ minutes
>   16.6%
>
> 68,378 responses
>
> When asked to compare the last time they solved a problem using Stack
>   Overflow and the last time they used another resource, about 40% of
>   developers say they save 30 minutes or more, and three-quarters of
>   developers agree that they save more than 11 minutes. Combined with
>   the previous results, we can estimate that, conservatively, Stack
>   Overflow saves 30 to 90 minutes of time per developer per week.

As you can see, it says nothing of the sort that the advert is claiming. The advert claims **all** answers save an average of 90 minutes, even the ones that are wrong presumably, and the averaging is done across developers, not the answers.

In addition, the question does appear to be biased in that doesn't allow for answers where SO took more time than using other resources or to account for where a problem wasn't solved at all. The explanation is very hand-wavey in getting to the final estimate.

Comment: In the UK, this is a trading standards laws violation and the advert cannot be displayed here.

Answer (score 18):

Thank you so much for this report! These ads have now been updated to better reflect the data they were based on.

[image]

You can read more about the [survey results these ads are based on here](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019#community-_-comparing-stack-overflow-to-other-resources).

Comment: Thanks for this, that seems like a much more fair claim in the ad based off the data.

Comment: Thanks from the bottom of my heart too.. While correcting it is a must, not many of the enterprise level company are willing to admit their mistake publicly.. I give you that one. Keep it up sis (n bros). /(^_^)