# "46.8+ Billion Times a developer got help" - how is this calculated?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

"46.8+ Billion Times a developer got help" is mentioned on the [about page](https://stackoverflow.com/company). How is this figure calculated?

Comment: Probably page-views and pixie dust. Or maybe they use upvotes? Would be a bit more potentially accurate, although they would still require pixie dust.

Comment: Reminds me of [Does every Stack Overflow question really save 90 minutes of developer time?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/391722/4642212).

Comment: Did they got help? It's just the marketing department of the company boosting. The number, even if it is the number of page impressions, probably doesn't say what they imply. It's probably more complicated.

Comment: All of those statistics are meaningless marketing BS. The only purpose of the specific numbers is to give a false aura of reliability to meaningless statements.

Comment: "46.8 Billion Times a student asked internet strangers to do their homework"

Comment: _How is this figure calculated?_ ... With an MBA CEO calculator instead of a SE who knows what a stack overflow actually is and why it's relevant to the brand name???

Comment: @user4642212 - perhaps the real question is "Does every Stack Overflow question degrade the aggregate debugging skills of the world population of programmers?".

Comment: @Michael: just remember - every lazy student you "help" is a potential future colleague who won't know sh*t. (I am, of course, incredibly guilty in this respect).

Comment: Wow!!! 61 Upvotes for my question, I can't believe this

Comment: Oh if only every question I ever viewed on SO helped me...

Answer (score 45):

I guess this is the [total number of views on Stack Overflow questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1307439/total-number-of-views-on-questions), but it's slightly outdated since SEDE says it's 49.3 billion. (On the other hand, 49.3 *is* 46.8**+**.) Also, SEDE doesn't record deleted questions; those may have helped too.

Comment: SEDE probably also doesn't record if a view is from curators that deemed a post off-topic / not an answer / spam.. :)

Comment: Equating total number of views on Stack Overflow questions to "the number of times a developer got helped" is really, really optimistic.  It wouldn't surprise me if the true statistic was something like one percent of views or less.

Comment: @RobertHarvey You are trying to talk some math and common sense here. Come on... All people are talking marketing and advertising these days. Everyone is a sales person selling not quite clear what.

Comment: @Scratte ...why wouldn't it count that?

Comment: @TylerH That's my point. It does count it, but did that view "help a developer"? There's no distinction when merely counting views. Also, the spammer/not-an-answerer/.. viewed the post too :)

Comment: @RobertHarvey "Really optimistic" is a far kinder way of putting it than I'd use.

Comment: If I find an SO post by googling for a problem, the probability that I get an answer there is about 30% (subjective estimate). Btw, it is still far the best on the whole Internet, and actually my only reason to think some positive about the site/company. I think, calculating the people who voted any answer up on a visit, would be a better estimation.

Comment: @peterh: Is Googling for a problem the only means by which you visit Stack Overflow?

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica I find myself putting `site:stackoverflow.com` in almost all of my Google Searches for programming-related problems

Answer (score 28):

[Glorfindel's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/401931/11407695) perfectly sums up the most likely basis of this "calculation".

I would only add that a metric including only *positively scored or accepted answers* would yield a much more precise statement, but no, nowadays numbers that do not transcend the total number of people on earth by some magnitude are deemed not good enough for marketing purposes.

Here is a small [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1307840/n-billion-times-a-developer-got-help) implementing the mentioned approach. The result is still impressive, ~ 0.1 billion (it can be even higher if we add answers with 0 score and "thank you" comments), but certainly nowhere near 46.8+.

If counted [by accepted answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1307856/n-billion-times-a-developer-got-help-accepted-only) only, the metric is 10 times lower, ~ 0.01 billion.

Comment: I would go with accepted answers, as lots of people will upvote simply because the answer is correct or well written.  For instance, I can’t imagine that the top voted answer has helped as many people with the same problem as have upvoted it.  It’s nevertheless an excellent answer well deserving of an upvote.

Comment: @jmoreno - yeah, I would probably go with the accepted answer as metric as well ( that said, as I am sure you know, there is a problem with new users not accepting answers no matter what... But that probably could be mitigated by counting "accepted answers + answers with no accept, but with a "thank you" comment")

Comment: "_would yield a much more precise statement_" - Why? Do you not feel that the act of helping others with negative scoring questions also helps the developer grow as a person? May help them feel better for doing so? In fact, the act of curating the site, removing bad questions, helps many more developers than just the viewer, every time one does so they help all developers the world over.

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland hm? By "more precise" I am comparing to "total number of views" most likely used in the statement. The problem with negatively scored posts is that the "helpfulness" of these is barely measurable. A positive score and/or accept on an answer is at least follows the definition of "helpful" on SO (take a look at the upvote and the accept checkmark tooltips). P.s. No need to get adversarial.

Comment: @jmoreno I agree that upvotes would probably vastly overestimate the number of people helped (but also maybe not, as I don't know how many people come here through Google and what percentage don't even have accounts to be able to upvote). However, accepted answers would likely vastly *under*estimate it. That discounts everyone who found an answer on Stack Overflow via a Google search or similar, which is a high-priority goal of the site and probably a much bigger number than the number of people who got their answer by asking a question.

Comment: I was thinking about just what @BernhardBarker just mentioned.  If we all agree that the majority of "help" comes from those coming later and just viewing existing questions, there's no way to know this "developers helped" number because it would have to intuit if a view of a page helped someone or not.  And since a lot of helped developers won't bother to upvote an answer that helps them (I'm guilty of this, although I try to do so), and as said before, viewers will upvote something that didn't really help THEM, my view is that there's just no way to know.

Comment: @BernhardBarker - as I mentioned, I fully agree that accepted answers (and even positively scored) are not the best possible metric there is. Just saying that even *that* is better than getting a number of views from analytics and slapping it all over the place... If we could somehow quantify those who were helped but did not upvote/accept the answer, then the metric would probably be 3-5 times higher than 0.1B.

Comment: @Steve - agreed, the actual number of those helped is likely to be higher (hell, even I do not upvote every good answer/question if I am in a rush + there is a thing like serial upvoting) than provided by the query (as you yourself mention, though, it is hardly formalizable - I can only think of "thank you" comments from the corresponding table, but that's also not accurate as they are rigorously deleted). I tend to think that *any* metric like this is meaningless, but it is my firm belief that the stats should at least be realistic and verifiable (even if that leads to underestimation)