# How to report a broken link that is now redirecting to malware or other unsavory content

Tags: support, flags, hyperlinks, broken-link

A link in an answer directs to a web site that tries to take over the computer. How should I report this to Stack Overflow so that it will remove the link?

The answer in the "Code Example" link:
[Is it possible to make a grayscale BMP file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417823/is-it-possible-to-make-a-grayscale-bmp-file)

At the time the link was posted, it was to a genuine website with no malware.

Comment: My sincerest apologies to whoever was affected.

Comment: Can someone provide details about this link/malware so we can be more careful in the future ? Thanks

Comment: @Berthim Since the answer is now deleted, here's the [archive link](http://web.archive.org/web/20100325060454/http://www.bobpowell.net/grayscale.htm). You can use that to determine the current link.

Comment: @MPelletier talking in "SO metrics" it's 3000 people were affected

Comment: @Kos MPelletier was not to know that the website would be taken over by malware ten years after the link was given.

Comment: @Kos Also, it is likely be that most of the 3000 *views* didn't involve clicking on the link, and, of those, many may have done so before the site became malware.

Comment: @Kos You gotta account for: visits since the edit (and from this post), visits since the deletion, visits before the site went bad. And out of the visits that were during the time of the compromised link, how many people actually clicked that link (we know of one). There are many unknowns.

Comment: @MPelletier sure, we talking about unknowns when something bad happened, but we definitely don't do this to celebrate how helpful SO is, for example: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401930/46-8-billion-times-a-developer-got-help-how-is-this-calculated

Answer (score 52):

If the answer consists of nothing more than a spam link and appears to be a blatant attempt to spam the site, then flag the entire answer for moderator intervention. If the problems are obvious, then just use the provided "spam" flag option. Otherwise, you can use the "in need of moderator intervention" option, which allows you to type a more detailed explanation to the moderator who will review your flag.

However, if the answer contains any content of value *aside* from the spam link, then you should not flag it as spam. You should instead act to fix the specific problem, without losing any valuable portions of the answer.

In this case, the answer was posted by an established user as part of an otherwise valid answer, and looking at it on the [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/) you can see that it **was** a legitimate link at the time it was posted, so you can simply edit it (or suggest an edit, if you don't have enough reputation) to replace the link with the archived version. I've already done so in this case.

This type of salvage/cleanup work does not require moderator intervention, and thus should not be flagged for moderator attention.

In the case of a flag or suggested edit (or simply [being in too big of a hurry](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416426)), you may also want to leave a comment warning people not to click the link until your flag/edit is processed.

Comment: Thanks for editing that answer. I guess I'll copy the code from the archived link and give credit to the archive... Man, what a shame that site has gone rogue...

Comment: @MPelletier Unfortunately, it happens from times to times but too regularly anyway...

Comment: Even with the link valid, it's still a link-only answer. Downvote, vote-to-delete, move on.

Comment: @JörgWMittag even if its just a link its still an answer. Copy in the summary of link content, update the link and move on.

Comment: This is just yet another reason why we shouldn't allow link-only answers. If this one isn't a link-only answer then I don't know what is. Stop putting lipstick on a pig and delete it.

Comment: Until what's suggested is done, it currently falls in the "not-an-answer" category, as [per this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/376026)

Comment: @Lundin The Question basically is "Is it possible to make a grayscale BMP file?", and this Answers say "Yes. If the colours are indexed, then you can set it to just the colours you want.". How is that not an Answer?

Comment: @Scratte No, the question is fine, it provides a reasonable amount of detail in addition to the title. It can be explained by addressing the various possible color formats of .bmp, some pseudo code if needed etc. The link-only answers are just being lazy.

Comment: @Lundin You keep calling this a link-only Answer. But it's **not**! There's a sentence there **before** the link that clearly answers the Question. Ask yourself this: If the link is removed, is there an answer there? Or an attempt of an answer? Or a wrong answer? Or a short answer? You may not agree with or find it useful, but it's clearly there.

Comment: @Scratte If the link is removed, the answer is 100% useless. The purpose of this site is not to be an archive of completely useless data that "is still an answer", in order to keep some policy lawyers on meta.so happy. The purpose of this site is to provide quality Q&A for the benefit of programmers.

Comment: Anyway, this debate of "we must hug crap" vs "we must delete crap" has been raging on meta for as long as I can remember. Users are in either camp, we won't settle it here. Use your votes and user moderator privileges as you see fit. I voted to delete it.

Comment: @Lundin That is interesting, because I found it useful :) But now.. I find Stack Overflow a little less useful. So while you think you're cleaning up, I see a post that did no harm being removed along with the information it provided me.

Comment: @Scratte The point here is that instead of clinging on to the mediocre one-liner sentence which doesn't help much in general, you could read a whole, detailed and high quality answer about the topic elsewhere on SO. With that in mind, the mediocre one-liner sentence did not add anything of value what-so-ever, it is just crap that distracts from the high quality posts about the topic, or from high quality posts in general. Post enough crap and you drown the high quality content in it, making it nearly impossible to find.

Comment: @Lundin You mean, along with the one-liner, there should have been a runnable code as an example?

Comment: @Clockwork Not necessarily. Describing the bitmap format or a (pseudo code) algorithm for color format conversions would be good answers too.

Comment: There's no good way of handling this. If it's malicious I'd say you should downvote and flag it, I've had some success with flagging stuff like this in the past but it's not 100%. If it's really bad use any other means necessary to get somebody's attention (chat, etc.), malicious links need to go away fast. Maybe the user who posted the content is still active but unfortunately the decay rate of SO accounts is about the same as the decay rate for personal blogs. Suggested edits aren't that effective for this, it'd be likely you'd just get rejected for "turd polishing".

Comment: More than once during browsing I've been very happy I use Linux as a main OS after stumbling on a "unpleasant" page unexpectedly, these days I treat unknown sites with a lot of suspicion, but SO tends to attract a higher caliber of users and content so I'm a bit more trusting. If we don't trash evil links that reputation will erode.

Comment: @jrh From what little I gathered, initial poster intended for the link to point toward some source code. But then, several years later, the website went wrong, so it became a malware nest. Basically another reason to copying the website's content into the answer.

Comment: @Clockwork yeah, it's surprisingly not that uncommon. I usually find malware links in blogs though (companies that went out of business, or individual blogs that got shut down, etc.). Copying the content into an answer is great but having references is always nice, even if it means more maintenance.

Comment: I'm very surprised to read reasoning by @Lundin. Has understanding of link-only answer changed so dramatically from [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)?

Comment: @eis It has never changed much. Again, it's the crap huggers vs crap deleters. Some people simply think that if I write a one-liner answer while drunk at the same time as the cat walks across my keyboard, then that post is some great tome of knowledge that must be preserved for eternity and deleting it would be a deadly sin.

Comment: Also FWIW, ublock origin has a few times been good at detecting  malware/crapware/not PG rated "oh snap I better close that tab" squatter sites. SO isn't the worst at this by any means (there's forums out there littered with "unpleasant surprise" links but we can, and need to do better).