# What should I do if an answer has a good-turned-bad link, and the replacement cannot be found?

Tags: discussion, external-links, broken-link

The link in an answer currently redirects to some casino advertisement (at least for me, maybe it behaves differently depending on location). Maybe the source still lives somewhere under a different link, but I could not find the replacement.

Should I, in such scenario, just remove the link? The downside is that URL isn't visible anymore, and if someone (willing to fix it) came later, they wouldn't know about it / wouldn't see the clues in the URL of what to search for.

Comment: *"I'm not in the mood to go searching"* - Then leave it to someone else?

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine sure, maybe, hence my question. Should I leave it or should I remove it

Comment: Does the wayback machine still has the original?

Comment: @rene Nope, just checked

Comment: Leaving a link to spam up does not seem like the best option, IMO.

Comment: If you're not gonna fix it, don't break it more.

Comment: @KevinB How is removing a link to spam breaking the post?

Comment: @KevinB breaking it is better than leaving it up

Answer (score 15):

If you're in a hurry and you can't now find a better replacement, just leave a single comment that has two messages:

- The link is stale and now points to a site that is not suitable for work (NSFW)
- I couldn't find a proper replacement now, if someone else does, please edit the link.

This comments achieves that both the OP and future visitors are informed about a serious issue with the post and it invites others to resolve the issue by  guiding them towards the steps needed to bring the content up to par.

Comments are meant to point out issues with a post.

Of course if there are other issues with the post that needs flagging / voting / editing, please do so. A single stale link might not be the end for awesome content but if the rest of the post isn't salvageable either then the whole exercise is moot.